# Quote discounts by applied rules

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

I need to get cart rules applied to a quote, with the discount amount related to them. Say I have the following:

```
**Rule 1**: Buy 2, get 1 free on product 1

**Rule 2**: 10% discount on all products

**Product 1**: $10

**Product 2**: $20

**Quote**

3 x Product 1

2 x Product 2

**Subtotal**: $70

**Discount**: $16

**Total**: $54
```

I am fetching applied rules through $quote->getAppliedRuleIds(), but cannot get the discount amount for each rule, for e.g.:

```
3x2 on product 1: **$10**

10% Spring Sale: **$6**
```

How can I fetch those discounts?
Please reply me.

Answer (score 0):

have same question. Now only way that I see is to get SaleRule Model by id and recalculate manually. But if salerule was changed it will be wrong, so we have to customize and save old sale rules in other table.

Comment: https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/save-items-discount-amount-per-couponrule-in-magento/ -  i think this can help